# php recursion function not working

Tags: php, recursion

I have a recursive function to show categories and sub categories, it works fine but it add extra `<ul></ul>` every where.

php code

```
<?php
     echo '<ul class="nav">';
     function mainMenu($parentId, $connection) {
     $sqlTours = "SELECT * FROM categories 
     WHERE category_parent = ".$parentId." ORDER BY category_order ASC";
     $rsTours = mysql_query($sqlTours, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
     $totalToursRows = mysql_num_rows($rsTours);

        echo "<ul>";
        while($rowsTours = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsTours)) {
         $categoryId = $rowsTours['category_id'];
         $categoryName = $rowsTours['category_name_en'];
         echo "<li>"
            <a href=\"products.php?category_id=".$categoryId ."\"
            data=\"".$categoryId."\">".$categoryName."</a>";

              mainMenu($categoryId, $connection);
              echo "</li>";

        }

        echo "</ul>";


}

mainMenu(0, $connection); 
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

and here is the html i'm getting from this function

```
    <ul class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="products.php?category_id=1" data="1">Egypt</a>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="products.php?category_id=2" data="2">Hurghada</a>
          <ul>
            <li> <a href="products.php?category_id=7" data="7">Sea Trips</a>
              <ul>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="products.php?category_id=6" data="6">Safari Trips</a>
              <ul>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="products.php?category_id=3" data="3">Sharm El Sheikh</a>
          <ul>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="products.php?category_id=4" data="4">Taba</a>
          <ul>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="products.php?category_id=5" data="5">Turkey</a>
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

and this is the expected output

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="products.php?category_id=1" data="1">Egypt</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="products.php?category_id=2" data="2">Hurghada</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="products.php?category_id=7" data="7">Sea Trips</a></li>
          <li><a href="products.php?category_id=6" data="6">Safari Trips</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="products.php?category_id=3" data="3">Sharm El Sheikh</a></li>
      <li><a href="products.php?category_id=4" data="4">Taba</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="products.php?category_id=5" data="5">Turkey</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And your question would be...?

Comment: It adds extra what? What is the expected output?

Comment: i just need the out put to be like i just edit my post by removing all the extra <ul></ul>

Comment: You always echo `echo "<ul>";` around a list, But that means you also do that inside the outer list (which was already explicitly outputted) and as well inside inner `li`s that don't have children. So you will need to make some more changes to check for those conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get rid of the empty `<ul></ul>` tags at the bottom of your recursive descent.

You already count the rows into `$totalToursRows`, so use that to prevent creating the empty nodes:

```
function mainMenu($parentId, $connection) {

    $sqlTours = "SELECT * FROM categories
    WHERE category_parent = ".$parentId." ORDER BY category_order ASC";
    $rsTours = mysql_query($sqlTours, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $totalToursRows = mysql_num_rows($rsTours);

    if ($totalToursRows > 0) {
        if ($parentId !== 0) {
            echo "<ul>";
        }

        while($rowsTours = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsTours)) {
            $categoryId = $rowsTours['category_id'];
            $categoryName = $rowsTours['category_name_en'];
            echo "<li>";
            echo "<a href=\"products.php?category_id=".$categoryId ."\"
                data=\"".$categoryId."\">".$categoryName."</a>";

            mainMenu($categoryId, $connection);
            echo "</li>";
        }

        if ($parentId !== 0) {
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }

}

mainMenu(0, $connection);
```

Edited per comment request.

Comment: ok perfect i lost the empty ul , but still there is a <ul> is wrapping the list (the very first <ul>) can we get ride of it as well so the out put will start with   <ul class="nav"><li>... instead of <ul class="nav"><ul><li>.... ?

Comment: @NasserKamal See amended code. Notice how I removed the specific `echo` for `<ul class="nav">` and pulled it inside of the recursive algoirthm.

Comment: i'm getting erorr says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'nav' "

Comment: @NasserKamal Check again - I edited it to escape the double quotes.

Comment: ok works now great , one last thing , is there a way not to show the wrapper <ul class ":nav" > at all , and the output will start with <li>

Comment: because will be more items will add after the functions such as <li>home page</li> and so ,, and those items are not in the tables